# How can I view the original (or "master") version of a photo in Photos without reverting all edits?

Tags: photos.app

Most photo applications provides some way to toggle between the original (unedited) version of a photo and the current (edited) one.

In Aperture, "M" toggles between the two, many iOS photo apps let you touch the screen to compare the edited or filtered version to the original, etc.

**I can't find any way to show the original in the new Photos app other than "reverting," which *removes* all the edits.**

I don't want to remove them, I just want to compare the two.

I realize that I can "revert" then undo, but it's hacky, slow, and worse, dangerous - counting on undo to preserve work in any app is iffy, at best.

Note: The fact that Aperture edits are saved "less destructively" than Photos shouldn't be relevant here.  Both applications DO retain the original, in edition to the edited version.

Comment: M seems to work for me, as @user129036 suggests.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While in Edit mode, *hold down* the <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd> keys.

This will show you the original version of your photo, with no edits applied. If you want to temporarily undo the effect of the color adjustments but keep the cropping and rotation the same, hold down <kbd>M</kbd> by itself.

Unlike Aperture:

- It doesn’t work in “view mode”; you have to be in edit mode. (To get into edit mode via the keyboard, press <kbd>Return</kbd>.)
- It’s a hold, not a toggle, so you only see the original photo for as long as you have the keys held down.

Comment: Thanks - really helpful. I think I missed it because I expected "m" to toggle, so I wasn't holding it long enough to see it work.

Comment: This isn't working for me in Photos Version 1.3 (350.23.0)

Comment: I’m using Photos 1.5 (370.42.0) and this doesn’t work for me either. Holding down `m` is still mentioned in the Keyboard Shortcuts window, though. I guess I’ll open a bug report…

Comment: It turns out that holding down `m` does work for me, but that it won’t undo certain kinds of edits: cropping, rotation by 90° (by clicking "Rotate"), or fine-grained rotation (by clicking "Crop") are not reset when you hold down `m`. I dislike this behavior and I opened a bug report telling Apple so. @SimonWoodside maybe this was the problem you were having too?

Comment: Apple told me that If you hold down Control and M then you can undo all of your edits, including cropping and straightening. I’ve edited the answer to include this information.

Comment: `m` alone is enough, `ctrl` is not needed (at least in the latest version 2.0 with macOS Sierra)

Comment: In Mojave, <kbd>Return</kbd> opens or closes the image in the full-window view (what spacebar did in earlier versions), and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> toggles edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

For now you could toggle between `CMD` + `Z` and `Revert to Original` from the `Image` menu.

Additionally you can make the process faster by adding a keyboard shortcut:

- Go to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` and then select `App Shortcuts`
- Click the `+` and select `Photos` from the app list
- Type 'Revert to Original' in the menu title field and choose a keyboard shortcut. I used `CMD` + `Y`.

Now you can flick back and forth by pressing `CMD` + `Y` and `CMD` + `Z`

Comment: On a sidenote, if you find yourself accidentally pressing `CMD` + `Z` when you needed the `CMD` + `Y`, you need to type `CMD` + `Shift` + `Z` to redo the undo, as you don't want to undo your last edit instead of reverting the image.

Answer (score 1):

Why not duplicate the photo (by right clicking) and then edit one of them. Now, clicking the right and left arrow will compare the original and your edits. You could delete the original when you're done, since it's still available by reverting the edits on the other image.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to export them =(